# How to add a new item in the embeddings vocabulary?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, pytorch

Imagine you have trained a model containing an Embedding layer.

Your model performs well and you're happy with your embedding.

Then, suddenly, you want to add a new item in your vocabulary.
In other words you want to compute the embedding of this new item.

Basically an Embedding layer is a lookup table, used to turn positive integers into dense vectors of fixed size, and now you want to consider a new integer that was not there during the training.

How can you do this **without** retraining the model from scratch?

Does it make sense (after some matrix shape adjustement) to relaunch the training freezing all the parameters except the ones used to embed the new item?

Comment: Please see the intro and NOTE in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info

Comment: Hi @desertnaut, if possible this question should be moved to https://datascience.stackexchange.com

Comment: I am afraid we cannot do this ourselves; feel free to delete this and post it there instead.

Answer (score 1):

Do the following:

1. Add a new row to your embedding matrix, randomly initialized. This row represents your new vocab item
2. Create a training dataset of inputs that use the new vocab item (make sure you've updated tokenizers/preprocessing/etc to produce the new vocab integer)
3. Freeze all the non-embedding parameters of the model
4. Fine-tune the model with the new dataset. Make sure to zero the gradients on all the old embeddings (ie only update the new embedding) to prevent the old embeddings from being trained